# TypeORM Join tables with subqueries

Tags: javascript, sql, mysql, nestjs, typeorm

I have a MySQL database and a Nestjs API that consumes this database. On the database, there are two main tables `users` and `reservations`. They have a OneToMany relation, that is, each reservation is associated with one user and each user can have many reservations.

I want to create a Query that lists all users and for each user, it returns the next most recent reservation. I've come up with this SQL query:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN reservations r
ON u.id = r.user_id
AND r.start_date = (
    SELECT MIN(start_date) FROM reservations r2
    WHERE r2.user_id = r.user_id 
    AND r2.start_date >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
    AND r2.status = 'OPEN'
);
```

How can I transform this query into a TypeORM query?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with a query builder combined with a subquery like so:

```
UserEntity.getRepository()
    .createQueryBuilder('user')
    .leftJoinAndSelect('user.reservations', 'r')
 .where(qb => {
      const sub = qb
        .subQuery()
        .select('MIN(start_date)')
        .from('reservations', 'r2')
        .where('r2.user_id = r.user_id')
        .andWhere('r2.start_date >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()')
        .andWhere('r2.status = :status', { status: 'OPEN' })
        .getQuery();

      return `r2.start_date = (${sub})`;
    });
```

See Typeorm docs on how to select using a query builder : https://typeorm.io/select-query-builder